# Save inherited object to separate collection in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, mongodb, collections, mongoid

I read up to inheritance in mongoid and it seems that all inherited classes will save in the base class, e.g.

```
class BaseClass
end

class ChildClass1 < BaseClass
end

class ChildClass2 < BaseClass
end
```

It seems that all these store in the BaseClass collection.

I actually want them to store in separate collections, e.g. `ChildClass1 - collection` and `ChildClass2 - collection`.

Comment: According to discussion on [this](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1133) issue I'd assume that there is no way to store subclasses in a separate collections. You can go with mixins instead of inheritance as durran suggests in this issue.

Comment: Is there any problem with using this:   self.collection_name = "account"? Obviously my goal is to keep my collections small. Is that a good idea anyway?

Comment: I found the good answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704310/mongoid-store-in-produces-random-results

Answer (score 4):

I realise this was posted a year ago, but this might be what you were looking for:

```
class BaseClass
  include Mongoid::Document
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    super
    subclass.store_in subclass.to_s.tableize
  end
end

class ChildClass1 < BaseClass
end

class ChildClass2 < BaseClass
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try this approach:

```
module Base
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  included do
    # Common code goes here.
  end
end

class ChildClass1
  include Base
end

class ChildClass2
  include Base
end
```

I do this in my Rails 5 app and it works for sure.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Testing/Working in a non-rails app

Comment: I tried it like this. I've got a class which has_many :child_class1s. When calling myClassInstance.childclass1s I get the error message "(Object doesn't support #inspect)".

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem and did not find a good solution on the web.
After few attempts, I developed a solution:

```
class A
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  ...
end


class B < A
  def self.collection_name
    :your_collection_name_1
  end
  ...
end


class C < A
  def self.collection_name
    :your_collection_name_2
  end 
  ...
end
```

Before any access to mongo collection, mongoid gets the collection name from 'collection_name' method.

This way, I override the method 'collection_name' of mongoid class, which returns the collection name (instead of the name of the base class with 's': 'As')

So, all the write (or read) commands from class B will insert (select) into 'your_collection_name_1' collection and class C will insert into 'your_collection_name_2' collection.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to do that. Because it's the concept of the STI In Mongoid like [explain by Durran the Mongoid creator](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1133#issuecomment-1767252)

If you really want save in several collection you need use Module include like :

```
class BaseClass
  include MyModule
end

class ChildClass1
  include MyModule
end

class ChildClass2
  include MyModule
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's good input. What about this? self.collection_name = "account"? is there any catch?

Comment: you need use the class method `store_in` to define in which collection you want save your object

Answer (score 0):

From Mongoid v8.1 onwards (Maybe v8.0 as well, haven't tested it in that version), you can use `store_in collection: "collection_name"` for this.

```rb
class Shape
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: :shapes
end

class Circle < Shape
  store_in collection: :circles
end
```

This will create the documents in 2 different collections (shapes and circles).

Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/current/reference/inheritance/#persistence-contexts